# Android - Get real name of user from Account Manager

Tags: android, accountmanager

I want to get user's real name from their Google account on their Android Phone.

I have been able to extract the email used from Account Manager but couldn't get name.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this my friend

```
public String getUsername() {
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this); 
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google"); 
String name;

for (Account account : accounts) {
  // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat
  // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type values. 
  name=account.name;

}

if (!possibleEmails.isEmpty() && possibleEmails.get(0) != null) {
    String email = possibleEmails.get(0);
    String[] parts = email.split("@");

    if (parts.length > 1)
        return parts[0];
}
return name;
}
```